# How can I get full, expanded, stringified macros from boost::wave?

Tags: c++, boost, c-preprocessor

I have a file containing the following:

```
#define str(s) s
#define xstr(s) #s
#define foo 4
#define first str(foo)
#define second xstr(foo)
```

When I pass this into boost::wave, the macromap contains the following:

```
first=str(foo)
foo=4
second=xstr(foo)
str(s)=#s
xstr(s)=str(s)
```

How can I get the macros to be fully expanded such that:

```
first="foo"
second=4
```

I thought that boost::wave supported macro re-scanning and lookup. Is there something I'm missing, or do I need to do something with the processing hooks to make the expansion happen? I mean, I can write code to descend the tree, but it would be certainly nice if I didn't have to do that work if I was missing something important.

Comment: I think you meant`#define str(s) #s` `#define xstr(s) str(s)`

Comment: You can redefine or undefine `str` down the road, but `firsr` still will have to expand to `str(foo)`. This is why it cannot be stored fully expanded.

Comment: Ah. This makes sense. In order to get the evaluation of a macro, I have to use it someplace, such as in something like `char const firstdef[] = first;` `int const secondeval = second;`

Answer (score 0):

The clue from n.m. was important. Macros may be defined and undefined whenever, so it's only the instance of use which is relevant.

This was far easier than I had expected. If I have something that looks like this in a header file:

```
#define str(s) #s
#define xstr(s) str(s)
...
#define MAJORVER 1
#define MINORVER 0
#define MAJORBUILD 0
#define MINORBUILD 1
#define FULLBUILDSTRING xstr(MAJORVER) "." \
                        xstr(MINORVER) "." \
                        xstr(MAJORBUILD) "." \
                        xstr(MINORBUILD)
```

The FULLBUILDSTRING macro will evaluate to just the string as declared. However, if I have some code that makes use of the macro directly, such as in

```
static char const full_build_string[] = FULLBUILDSTRING;
```

It will evaluate to the following when Wave processes it:

```
static char const full_build_string = "1" "." "0" "." "0" "." "1";
```

If you need to see how the macros are defined after processing is complete, you can always do something like so (this is taken from the Wave driver code):

```
auto end = ctx.macro_names_end();
for (auto it = ctx.macro_names_begin(); it != end; ++it) {
   typedef std::vector<context_type::token_type> parameters_type;
   bool has_pars = false;
   bool predef = false;
   context_type::position_type pos;
   parameters_type pars;
   context_type::token_sequence_type def;
   if (ctx.get_macro_definition(*it, has_pars, predef, pos, pars, def)) {
      // if has_pars is true, you can iterate through pars to see 
      // parameters for function macros
      // iterate through def to see the macro definition
   }
}
```

Of course, the macros are stored in non-expanded form.

(n.m., if you write an answer, I will accept it)